# Force all tasks to run when executing artisan schedule:run

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, laravel-artisan

We have scheduled some tasks to run every 6 hours on production server.

In `kernel.php` :

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->exec('some/command')
        ->cron('* */6 * * *');
}
```

I know that I can force this task to run if replacing the `->cron()` with `->everyMinute()`, and then run `artisan schedule:run`. But is there another way to run this task so we don't have to mess with the code on a live server?

If there's no other solution we just have to wait 6 hours.

Answer (score 1):

All the scheduler does is call artisan with whatever arguments you send. You can do the same by using `artisan` on the command line.

```
 php artisan some/command
```

Comment: This `some/command` is actually somewhat complicated with a lot of env vars. It would be easiest to run the task for us I think.